# What is need of copy_from_user

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

If kernel can access user space why do we need copy_from_user to copy data in kernel memory, why it just cant access user space data? is it for performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kernel and user space do not necessarily have the same address space. They can be entirely separate, requiring special CPU instructions to move data between them.

The other important point is that the kernel needs to access user space with user permissions, i.e. if the user space program accessing that address would fail, then `copy_from_user()` will also fail, even if the kernel could access that address by itself.

Apart from general access violations, permission failure can also include a page not being in memory because it resides on disk. This may require some kind of special set up since normally the kernel does not use swappable memory.

Comment: could you please elaborate more 2nd and 3rd point

Comment: It has been already explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666493/why-do-you-have-to-use-copy-to-user-copy-from-user-to-access-user-space-from