# Will direct accessing of user space address instead of copy_to_user work?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

The following is an excerpt from my simple driver code.

```
int vprobe_ioctl( struct file *filep, unsigned int cmd, void *UserInp)
{
    case IOCTL_GET_MAX_PORTS:

        *(int*)UserInp = TotalPorts;

    #if ENABLED_DEBUG
        printk("Available port :%u \n ", TotalPorts);
    #endif
        break;
}
```

I was not aware about the function `copy_to_user` which should be used while writing on user space memory. The code directly accesses the user address. But still I am not getting any kernel crash in my development system(x86_64 architecture). It works as expected.

But sometimes I could see kernel crash when I insert the .ko file in some other x86_64 machines. So, I replaced direct accessing with `copy_to_user`, and it works.

Could anyone please explain,

i) How direct accessing of user address works?

ii) Why am I seeing kernel crash in some systems whereas it works well in some other systems. Is there any kernel configuration mismatch between the systems because of which the kernel could access the user process's virtual address directly?

Note : All the systems I have used have same OS and kernel.-same image generated thru kickstart. - There is no possibility of any differences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666493/why-do-you-have-to-use-copy-to-user-copy-from-user-to-access-user-space-from). There is also `put_user()` that might be better for your case of single int.

Comment: @RomanKhimov From the question you mentioned, I understand that `copy_to_user` does check whether the address belong to user space. My doubt is how direct accessing works. Also, why direct accessing works in some systems and doesn't work in some other systems with same OS and kernel.

Answer (score 1):

would be interesting to see the crash. now what I'm saying is an assumption based on my knowledge about how the memory works.
user space memory is virtual. it means that the specific process address X is now located on some physical memory, this physical memory is a memory page that is currently allocated to your process. copy to user first checks that the memory given really belongs to the process and other security checks. beside that there is mapping issues.

the kernel memory has its own address space that need to map virtual to physical address. the kernel use the help of mmu (this is different per architecture). In x86 the mapping between the kernel virtual and user virtual is 1:1 (there are different issues here). In other system this is not always true.

Comment: //In x86 the mapping between the kernel virtual and user virtual is 1:1// So, you are saying that kernel virtual address and user virtual would be same and so I could use user virtual directly in kernel. Am I right? But all the systems I have used are x86 systems with same OS image.